# Multiple dns lookups

Tags: dns

I just ran a load time analysis for a website. The results can be seen here:

http://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.parship.co.uk/VfLleffe

When you check the timeline you will see that some images have a dns lookup time and some do not. Even when the images are on the same subdomain some require a dns lookup and some do not.

Is this totally random? Or is there a way to prevent multiple dns lookups for the same subdomain?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

That's a simple answer - if you reference the images in your html with the site's domain name it will trigger a DNS lookup.

This will not trigger a DNS lookup:

```
<img src="/logo.png" alt="Site Logo" />
```

This will trigger a DNS lookup:

```
<img src="http://www.mysite.com/logo.png" alt="Site Logo" />
```

Comment: References for this alleged behaviour?  I've seen YSlow report similar even when all links were relative.

Comment: I'll go try to find some but I've seen this from personal experience.  Are you using a "/" in front of some of the images and not others?  Have you tried setting the base tag in the html header?

<base href="www.mysite.com/sitedir/"></base>